# IP Encriptada google chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome

estoy consultando la IP local de mi PC usando Javascript.

Usando el navegador Chrome me devuelve: f4530874-7960-4b2b-bca2-7ab21b20567a.local
Pero si uso Firefox me devuelve: 192.0.0.0
No entiendo porque, necesito ayuda.

```js
//compatibility for firefox and chrome
if (window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection ||
    window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection) {

  var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: []
    }),
    noop = function () {};
  pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
  pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop); // create offer and set local description
  pc.onicecandidate = function (ice) { //listen for candidate events

    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate) return;

    var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];
    console.log(myIP);
  };
}
```

Comment: Usando Chrome obtengo mi IP correctamente: 172.26.0.62. No puedo reproducir tu escenario.

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error: 
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 27,
  "colno": 110
}

Comment: Por otro lado te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida para conseguir tu primera medalla, aunque la pregunta está bien planteada, con un [mcve] bien claro.

Comment: A mi me funciona en windows y firefox...

Comment: A mi también me funciona en Chrome y Firefox con la diferencia de que en Firefox el log aparece dos veces y en Chrome solo una vez.